# How to induce a connection on a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose an [affine connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection#Formal_definition_as_a_differential_operator) is given on a smooth manifold $M$ and let $N\subset M$ be an embedded submanifold. Is there a canonical way of defining an induced connection on $N$?

In classical differential geometry of smooth surfaces in Euclidean 3-space, the corresponding construction is that of *covariant derivative* (cfr. Do Carmo, *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces* §4-4). The covariant derivative of a vector field along a curve on the surface is defined as the orthogonal projection of the ordinary Euclidean derivative onto the plane tangent to the surfaces.

I wonder how (and if) this can be ported to the language of connections.[Wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection#Surface_theory_revisited) does something like that by means of the Riemannian structure: I wonder if this extra structure is really necessary.

Comment: A connection more or less tells you how to move tangent vectors consistently from $T_p M$ to $T_q M$. The point about the Riemannian metric is, that it defines orthogonal projections $T_p M \rightarrow T_p N$ if $p\in N$, providing a natural means to induce a connection on $N$.  Unless you have some natural projection you will have difficulties to find a canonical way to define a connection on $N$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With just an affine structure you will not be able to get an induced connection. (Part of the story is told in Fox's [AMS Notices article from March 2012](http://www.ams.org/notices/201203/index.html) titled "What is an affine sphere?".)

Instead, you can consider the following for codimension 1 submanifolds: given $\tau:N\to M$ an embedding and let $v$ be a vector field on $M$ along $N$ that is transverse to $N$, then $(\nabla,v)$ on $M$ together induces a connection on $N$. For $(X,Y)$ vector fields on $N$, we can define
$$ D^{(v)}_X Y = [\nabla_{\tau_*X}\tau_*Y] $$
where $[W]$ for $W\in T_pM$, $p\in \tau(N)$ is defined by $\tau_*[W] - W = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. For higher codimension case you need more (linearly independent) vector fields. In the Riemannian case, $v$ is canonically chosen to be the unit normal vector to $N$ (or in higher codimension, a family that spans the normal bundle).

Comment: This is all fine and correct, but due to the fact that your transverse vector field(s) is(are) quite arbitrary it is far from being canonical.

Comment: @Thomas: precisely. The answer is (a) meant to illustrate the fact that the choice of a canonical "induced connection" is quite intimately connected with the choice of a canonical traverse vector field and (b) give reference to the fact that meaningful geometry can still be studied without such a canonical choice.

Comment: So if $M$ is a metric manifold, then $v$ can be canonically chosen to be the normal to the surface, right?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: I am not sure what you mean by metric manifold. Can you give me a reference?

Comment: I mean a riemmannian or pseudo-riemannian manifold. A metric in every tangent space. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: In the Riemannian case: yes. In the pseudo-Riemannian case, not necessarily: the "normal vector field" may not be transversal. You have to add the condition that the induced metric on the submanifold $N$ is non-degenerate. @JackozeeHakkiuz

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for coming back to such an old question.