# Pullback-connection

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The standard connection on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\nabla_XY= \sum_{ij=1}^2 X^i \partial_i Y^j \partial_j.$

I was wondering how to calculate the induced connection of this on $\mathbb{S}^1$

More precisely, let $X,Y$ be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are also in $T\mathbb{S}^1,$ then we can write them as functions of $x$ on the upper and lower part of the circle such that $x \mapsto X(x,\sqrt{1-x^2}) \in T_{(x,\pm \sqrt{1-x^2})}\mathbb{S}^1.$

I would like to know how the induced connection on the sphere now looks-like.

Comment: The usual way to think about the induced connection on a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ is to differentiate using the connection on $\Bbb R^2$ (in your case) and project the result onto the tangent space of the submanifold. (If you've not played around with this before, you might get some intuition from my (free) [differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) — see in particular section 2.4.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't have a notion of an "induced connection" on a submanifold. That is, if $N \subseteq M$ is a submanifold and you have a connection $\nabla$ on $M$, you can't get a connection on $N$ without some extra data (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155173/how-to-induce-a-connection-on-a-submanifold) for details).

However, in your case the connection you work with on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the Levi-Civita connection of the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In this case, you endow $S^1$ with the induced Riemannian metric and consider the associated Levi-Civita connection. If we work with the coordinate system $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ on $S^1$, the metric has the form $d\theta^2$ and so the associated Levi-Civita connection has the form

$$ \nabla_{f \partial_{\theta}}(g \partial_{\theta}) = f \partial_{\theta}(g) \partial_{\theta}.$$

Comment: I don't fully agree with this. If you have some sort of split $ TM|_\Sigma=T\Sigma\oplus S $, where $\Sigma$ is the submanifold, $TM|_\Sigma$ is the restricted tangent bundle and $S$ is some complementary subbundle then for a connection $\nabla$, we have an induced connection by the projection of $\nabla$ to $\Sigma$ (projection generated by the split). Of course, the most natural way to obtain such a split is to have a Riemannian metric and have $S$ be the normal bundle, but even then $\nabla$ doesn't have to be the Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: @Uldreth: For me, such a splitting is "extra data". And if the connection on $M$ was the Levi-Civita connection of a metric $g$ then the splitting you get using the metric together with projecting gives you the Levi-Civita connection of the induced metric on $\Sigma$.