Derivation of the gradient on the n-sphere
Let us consider a function $f:\mathbb{S}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We know that the Riemannian gradient of $f$ is given by:
$$
1)  \quad \nabla_{S^{n}} f(x)=\nabla_{\mathbb{R}} \bar f(x)-\langle\nabla_{\mathbb{R}} \bar f(x), x\rangle \cdot x,
$$
where $\bar f$ is any extension of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.
To derive such an equation I would like to use the general formula for Riemannian gradient, that is, in coordinates:
$$
2)\quad \nabla f=\sum_{i, j=1}^n g^{i j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}.
$$
What kind of metric tensor $g^{ij}$ for spheres must I plug in $2)$ to obtain the explicit formula in $1)$?

Two things. First, when you say "We know...", I have to ask, how do we know? Even better, how do you know? Is this something you are accepting on authority? Or is there some proof of 1) that you already know but that you don't like?

Second, you give some formula "in coordinates" without specifying the coordinates, which gives your question a certain vagueness. Do you have a specific set of coordinates in mind? Do you have a plan for choosing coordinates and applying the general formula for Riemannian gradient?

@LeeMosher First, I saw it from few different references without a formal proof, that's why I'm asking the question. Second, i didn't specify the coordinates exactly because that's my question. Maybe polar coordinates. I tried out something, but it doesn't match, it could also be a matter of notation tho.

Okay, fair enough. The second thing, though, is that your formula 1) does not make sense. Putatively $\nabla_{S^n} f$ on the left hand side, versus $\nabla f$ on the right hand side, are two different things. I would have expected $\nabla f$ on the right hand side to simply be the ordinary Euclidean gradient for a function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. However, your function is only defined on $\mathbb S^n$. Is it your intention that $f$ extends, somehow, to $\mathbb R^{n+1}$?

@LeeMosher yes that's exactly what I meant. I edited the question so it's more clear.

You might want to check Muller's book, there is an appendix or an introductory chapter, can't remember which one, devoted precisely to this computation.

@GiuseppeNegro Thanks, I'm looking at the book but I don't see anywhere this computation in details. Maybe he has a complete different notation and terminology?

@mathbb: it might be buried in the "no preview available" pages, then. Hopefully I'll have time to have a look at the book later.

@GiuseppeNegro I see. Thanks for the answer. But if I don't want to use spherical coordinates? In Muller's book there is the computation without using a precise coordinate chart? Let me know if you find the computation in the book. Thanks again.

You may want to check formula (1.8.12), pag.26, on https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6660-4. That's exactly the one you want. It does use coordinates, though. Precisely, Cartesian coordinates on $\mathbb R^d$.

@GiuseppeNegro Thanks again. It is exactly $1)$ in my question, but the derivation doesn't really seem what I'm asking for. Thanks anyway.

Ok. Now I am sure that this is ultimately what you are looking for. It is another ancient question of mine. That is concerned with the general case: instead of the sphere as a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$, my question is about a general submanifold of some ambient differentiable manifold. The answer by Willie makes it clear that, to induce a connection on the submanifold, a Riemannian structure is needed. And in that case, what Willie does is exactly what you are looking for, though in a general and perhaps cryptic way. HTH

@GiuseppeNegro thanks again. I see that in some sense there is an answer to what I'm asking in a very very general way, but to me it's a very unclear and cryptic answer.

Unfortunately, there is an "uncertainty principle" at work here. If you want a coordinate-free answer, then you have no choice but going through that other question & answer, with connections. Maybe it can be made a bit clearer, but ultimately it is what it is. Indeed, connections are made precisely for that: making differential operators coordinate-free. If you don't want connections, that's perfectly fine, but then you will need to compute in coordinates, as every answer here proposes (including mine).

@GiuseppeNegro Yes yes I got these points. I was just noticing that the answer itself in that post it's a bit unclear, that's it. Anyway everything is more or less clear on how to derive it. Thanks again for your time and your answers.

The Riemannian metric on $\mathbb S^n$ is simply the restriction of the standard Euclidean Riemannian metric on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ defined by $dx_1^2+\cdots+dx_{n+1}^2$. If you want to express this Riemannian metric in a chosen coordinate chart $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb S^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$, simply apply the pullback operator $\phi^*$ to the Euclidean Riemannian metric. If you want coordinate charts to do this with, use any old standard coordinate charts that cover the sphere. For example there are these this two which cover all but $x_n=0$
$$\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \bigl(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\pm\sqrt{1-x_1^2-...-x_n^2}\bigr) \qquad x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2<1
$$
and similar ones for all $i=1,...,n$ which cover all but $x_i=0$.

Thanks, but can you argue a bit more? For instance, what do I obtain explicitly making the pullback of the Euclidean metric using that chart and does it really give me $1)$ if I plug what I obtain in $2)$?

So you need to know how to compute the pullback?

The point is, what pullback I should compute in such a way that I obtain $1)$, because you gave an example of chart, but is that the right one to obtain $1)$? Can I use whatever coordinate chart covering the sphere to obtain $1)$?

It does not matter which coordinate chart you use to compute the Riemannian gradient, because the coordinate formula for the Riemannian gradient vector gives a vector that is well defined in the tangent space of the Riemannian manifold, independent of the coordinate chart. Perhaps that is actually the real issue underlying your question?

Maybe yes. Then I should just try to compute the pullback to the Euclidean Riemannian metric with whatever coordinate chart I prefer that covers the sphere, and then try to plug the result in $2)$ to see if I obtain $1)$.

I recommended having a look in Muller's book but apparently it is behind a paywall. Another possibility is to use spherical coordinates. The page https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html has a formula for the Euclidean gradient in $\mathbb R^3$ in spherical coordinates. From there it is easy to compute the projection onto tangent planes on the unit sphere, which are obtained by setting $r=1$ and projecting onto the span of $\hat\phi, \hat \theta$. This is the first formula of the question. Now it is just a matter of plugging in the metric coefficients $g^{ij}$, which are also given in the linked page, and concluding that the two formulas are the same.

ADDED LATER. A curious remark. It seems that I asked a similar question myself 12 years ago: Differential operators on the sphere

ADDED EVEN LATER. This is another 12 years old question of mine which is strictly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155202/8157.
That question is concerned about a more general setting. Here, we have $\mathbb S^{n}$ as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. There, I was asking about a general submanifold of some differentiable manifold. Here we talk about "gradient", there I was asking about inducing a "connection", which is the geometric device that unifies and generalizes the gradient and all other differential operators.
The answer by Willie Wong contains a recipe to construct a connection on a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold. That recipe, when specialized to the sphere, will produce exactly the first formula of the present question.
